# How to find Eclipse Extension Point's default implementation

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Is there an easy way to navigate to the Class which currently implements a given extension point?

For example I am looking for `org.eclipse.jdt.core.javaFormatter`
but I can't find the default implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the "Search > Search..." dialog and select the "Plug-in Search" tab.

Enter the extension point to search for in the "Search string" field - org.eclipse.jdt.core.javaFormatter in this case.

Set "Search for" to "Extension point", "Limit to" to "Refererences", "Scope" to "Workspace"

[image: Search dialog]

Comment: Then double-clicking on the extension point in the search results is how to actually open the plugin.xml that defines the class in question.

Answer (score 1):

It's `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.formatter.DefaultCodeFormatter`.

With PDE installed, you only have to open the plugin.xml file declaring that extension point, and on the Extension Points tab of the editor, select that one and click the "Find references" link under the Extension Point Details section.